# Can I use previous installation which was interrupted for my next installation in pip?

Tags: python, pip

I was installing **tensorflow-gpu(python)** in my windows using pip in command prompt. The installation got cancelled due to sudden network problem. Pip had already downloaded 300 MBs. So when I start the installation again, pip starts the installation from scratch. **Is there any way I can skip the downloading of files which have been previously installed?** Because this is not the first time I am facing this and downloading the same thing again and again is just a wastage of time and internet.

Comment: `pip download tensorflow-gpu --dest wheelhouse/` will download the files, then `pip install tensorflow-gpu --find-links=wheelhouse/` to install from local FS.